# Connecting fluorescent lights

Tags: electrical

this is my first time here and I hope you will appreciated that I am no expert in this.
I live in Australia by the way.

In my shed I have one fluorescent light with one switch.
I have added an extra fluorescent light over the bench in parallel and I am using the same switch. That is all OK.
Now I have picked the power from the existing light junction box and extended the wiring to feed another fluorescent light at the back of the shed.
In between those two lights (Fluo) I have put a switch to activate only the last light in the back of the shed.
I am not sure how should I connect the wires in the junction box to activate the light at the back of the shed.
I was thinking of connecting the (Red, A, or L) Active coming from the previous junction box to the Active going to the switch box
Then The Black from the switch box to go to the last light  (A, L) (back of shed)
The Neutral (Black, Blue, N) are connected together in the junction box and directly to the light at the back of the shed.

Could somebody kindly advise me if I am about to stuff it up or is it the right way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it right.

In the US one would put the switch (if a simple switch) in the hot line and the neutral and ground would run through to the new fixture. This achieves the effect that when the switch is off there is nothing hot past the switch. Some simple switches have a ground connection so one would attach a ground to them and the ground would go on from there. Some modern switches require that a neutral be connected to the switch because the switch itself consumes power. There will still be a continuous neutral from the line to the light. The switch does not break the neutral when the switch is off.

In practice one length of cable would enter the box from the line and one would leave to the light ot be switched. The two grounds would be connected according to Australian practice (and one short piece of wire would be connected to the other two to go to the ground contact of the switch if any). The two neutrals would be connected (and if, and only if, the switch requires a neutral, one short piece of wire would be connected to the two neutrals to go to the neutral contact on the switch). The hot line wire is connected to the switch line contact and the other hot to the load contact.

It is also important to have the hot and the neutral paired and running beside each other in the same cable or conduit. Once inside a box it is OK for them to not be parallel.

Comment: Is it possible to have a problem with induced emf within a box if the current carrying wires are looped in some way especially looped around the ground conductor?

Comment: I would say that would be a good question to ask separately! I think the answer is "no" but maybe some sparky's could chime in...